# Setting GroupBoxes in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder, groupbox

I am kind of newbie em Java and right now I am trying to program a simple GUI. Recently, I was looking for some kind of GroupBox (for WindowBuilder if possible), like the "Search" and "Overview" Groupboxes in the following image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img812/7239/jxsv.jpg

So, which graphical object would be nice for it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a `TitledBorder` that includes a lowered etched (`EtchedBorder.LOWERED`) border on a separate `JPanel` container using Swings `BorderFactory`. Read [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would simply place the controls onto a `JPanel` with a `TitledBorder`.

Further reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html